# GetAtt Outputs vs. ImportValue

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm sure I'm missing something quite obvious here, but what is the difference between getting an output value in a parent template of a stack with `GetAtt` and `ImportValue`? Is there a time and place where you can only use one or the other? Are there places where they're interchangeable, but one is preferable for some reason?

For example, in a parent template:

```
myvpc:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  <some stuff to pass to a child template>

anotherresource:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
```

Then either

```
      Subnet:
        !GetAtt [mypvc, Outputs.publicsubnet1]
```

or

```
      Subnet:
        !ImportValue 'MyVpcStackName:publicsubnet1'
```

Like I said, I'm probably missing something obvious, but I keep reading both document pages, and ... I'm not getting something.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I at least partially figured this out.

Short answer: don't use `ImportValue` in a nested stack, because you can't, because you don't know the sub-stack's name.

Long answer: Apparently it comes down to information sharing. I don't know why I couldn't find this yesterday, but [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html#output-vs-nested) says "if you want to isolate information sharing to within a nested stack group, we suggest that you use nested stacks [and `GetAtt`]. To share information with other stacks (not just within the group of nested stacks), export values [and `ImportValue`]." But it's not actually just about whether you want to share information, it's about what information you have available. Although it's not specified in [Specifying Stack Name and Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-console-create-stack-parameters.html), the [CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) explains that "The name must be unique in the region in which you are creating the stack.". To use `ImportValue`, you need to know the name of the stack from which you're importing, but when you create a nested stack, the sub-stacks are given randomly generated suffixes, to satisfy this constraint, so you don't actually know the name.

So, if you have

```
infrastructure-parent:
  -> vpc
  -> security-groups
  -> bastion
  -> NAT
  -> ALB
database-parent:
  -> RDS
  -> phpMyAdmin
```

For bastion to use something from security-groups, you use `GetAtt`. But for RDS to use something from vpc, you use `Export`/`ImportValue`, both because you *can't* use `GetAtt`, and because you don't know the name of the generated vpc stack (ergo, you create a vpcStackName parameter in RDS (and database-parent) to allow passing the name).

I guess the tricky part comes (and this is where my original confusion was generated) when you try to then nest multiple levels. So, if you take the above, and try to do

```
environment-parent:
  -> infrastructure-parent
  -> database-parent
```

the environment-parent needs to know the stack name that got generated for vpc, so it can pass it as a parameter to database-parent (which then passes it to RDS). Thus, the RDS and database-parent templates don't need to change, but the vpc template needs to `Output` the `AWS::StackName` [pseudo parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackname). infrastructure-parent can then get this using `GetAtt`, and then `Output` it *again* so that it's available for `GetAtt` in environment-parent, which can then pass it as a parameter to database-parent.

Comment: If you create a vpcStackName parameter in database-parent, how do you fill in the value of this parameter? Since you do not know the name of the nested vpc stack.

Comment: @xtra It's not a parameter in database-parent, it's an output. e.g., in database-parent:
`Outputs:
  VpcStackName:
    Value:
      !GetAtt [myvpc, Outputs.StackName]`

Answer (score 0):

I think part of what is confusing you is that you probably are doing things with substacks that are illadvised. According to [CloudFormation Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html)

> Use Nested Stacks to Reuse Common Template Patterns

If you do that, you shouldn't be exporting things from the substack, and you don't have the confusion.

Given what you are doing the reason you should still avoid the `ImportValue` is that you won't be able to delete the stack because of a self reference. I'm not sure you could even create it because I think it might evaluate the `ImportValue` early, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe this should be re-asked as a separate question, but, what's a good example of reusing a common template pattern? Because, that's exactly what I thought I was doing, and exactly why I need to export values (and then retrieve them, whether that be with ImportValue or GetAtt). I'm doing something different, but started with https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-refarch-wordpress. They, for example, have a nested stack which calls a VPC stack and a Bastion stack which relies on the formers outputs. I was thinking both "bastion" and "VPC" are common patterns. What's a better example?